# WCF .net 4.5.1 is encrypting headers, how do I prevent that?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I am consuming a java web service managed by a government ministry so I have no control over the service itself.  Recently Microsoft has released an update that requires I move up to at least .net 4.5.1 from the current 4.0.  This is because 4.0 does not support TLS1.2.  The problem I'm having now is that when the SOAP message goes out the header portion is encrypted.

eg:

```
<s:Header>
<k:EncryptedHeader s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4"    xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
<e:EncryptedData xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
<e:CipherData>
<e:CipherValue>DHlMcPGTl1ldE5Xza40Cit .... etc ...etc...
```

whereas on 4.0 it was only signed so I could see the data elements in the SOAP header.

The service is now rejecting my requests because of this and they are not going to change it.  How do I get WCF to stop encrypting the header?

Comment: Show your binding configuration - most likely it's something in the binding that you need to set (or unset).  This may require a custom binding.

Comment: Yes it already is a custom binding.  I'm not using a config file, everything is done in code.  As I mentioned, it works fine in 4.0 but in 4.5.x they've introduced this EncryptedHeader element.  I just want to turn that off.